# Iterate through folders and find a file to put into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a directory `../customer_data/*` with 15 folders. Each folder is a unique customer.

Example: `../customer_data/customer_1`

Within each customer folder there is a csv called `surveys.csv`.

GOAL: I want to iterate through all the folders in `../customer_data/*` and find the `surveys.csv` for each unique customer and create a concatenated dataframe. I also want to add a column in the dataframe where it has the customer id which is the name of the folder.

```
import glob
import os
rootdir = '../customer_data/*'
dataframes = []
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    
    for file in files:
        csvfiles = glob.glob(os.path.join(rootdir, 'surveys.csv'))
        
        # loop through the files and read them in with pandas
         # a list to hold all the individual pandas DataFrames
      
        df = pd.read_csv(csvfiles)
        df['customer_id'] = os.path.dirname
        dataframes.append(df)
            
# concatenate them all together
result = pd.concat(dataframes, ignore_index=True)
result.head()
```

This code is not giving me all 15 files. Please help

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module for this.

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

dfs = []
for filepath in Path("customer_data").glob("customer_*/surveys.csv"):
    this_df = pd.read_csv(filepath)
    # Set the customer ID as the name of the parent directory.
    this_df.loc[:, "customer_id"] = filepath.parent.name
    dfs.append(this_df)

df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try pathlib with `rglob` which will recursively search your directory structure for all files that match a `glob` pattern. in this instance survey.

```
import pandas as pd 
from pathlib import Path

root_dir = Path('/top_level_dir/')

files = {file.parent.parts[-1] : file  for file in Path.rglob('*survey.csv')}

df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file).assign(customer=name) for name,file in files.items()])
```

Note you'll need Python 3.4+ for pathlib.